# Vue 2: Transition not working on component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I have an animation that works on other components but does not work with this one.  I tried `<transition-group>` with no luck as well.  The row simply disappears without any animation.

```
<transition name="card-animation">
    <tr is="employee-row" 
        v-for="employee in employees" 
        :employee="employee" 
        :selectedOffice='selectedOffice'
        :new_hire_location_options="new_hire_location_options"
        v-on:fire='fireEmployee(employee)'
        v-if="(employee.location.name == selectedOffice || selectedOffice == 'show all')">
    </tr>
</transition>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.card-animation-enter-active, .card-animation-leave-active {
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out, opacity 0.25s ease-out;
}

.card-animation-enter, .card-animation-leave-to {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**What is wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `transition-group` to work with `v-for`. If you are using a string template, you also need the `tag="tbody"` attribute.

If you are using a DOM template, you need to use `<tbody name="card-animation" is="transition-group">`. Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3907

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2LLkene5/

Comment: As stated in the question I've tried `<transition-group>` and it didn't work

Comment: But did you also use the `tag="tbody"` attribute? You have to use transition-group to animate list changes, there's no other way.

Comment: to which element?  `<transition-group>` or the `<tr>`

Comment: transition-group. `<transition-group tag="tbody" name="card-animation>"`

Comment: still no animation.  I think the issue is that each `<tr>` is the component `employee-row` and I'm looping through `employees` and designating each `<tr>` as `employee-row` and trying to animate them at the same time.  My issue is that using the `is` keyword is my only way to display properly

Comment: I've updated your fiddle to represent my issue.  Can you try to make it work? https://jsfiddle.net/2LLkene5/2/

Comment: Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/2LLkene5/4/. Make sure you have a `key` on `tr` when using transition-group

Comment: mine still isn't working but it must be something else.  I'll accept your answer as it solved my initial question

Comment: Elements inside are always required to have a unique key attribute